How to add external font in Gtk without installing it?
Have a Gtk project and with Pango can use custom fonts, but need use a specific font from the project only without install it on the system, need change only a specific text. I can't set a new font via arguments or gtk settings because I only need to make this change to one button, not the entire application, nor can I ask the user to install my custom font so I can use the application.
Is there a possibility to make the css style sheet detect my local text font using Gtk, Gdi and Pango? @font-face is not supported in Gtk.
